# R coercing text to numeric

Tags: r, date, text, numeric

I am importing an excel file in R. The file contains two date columns. In excel these are formatted as Date (dd-mm-yyyy).

Importing the file in R, I get tthe following warning message:

```
In read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet,  :
  Coercing text to numeric in D1497 / R1497C4: '0.0000'
```

And the values are as 42710, 42678, etc ..

I need to use the columns as date.

I tried with commands like `as.Date()`, `mdy()` but , as consequence, the values are then replaced by NA.

From package tidyxl, I tried is_date_format but I get FALSE.

Could you help me? Have you any suggestion?

Thank you so much

PS: Here some values from the two columns in excel:

```
from_unixtime('%d/%m/%Y')   from_unixtime('%d/%m/%Y')
 06/12/2016                      06/12/2018
 04/11/2016                      08/09/2017
 04/11/2016                      08/09/2017
 01/12/2016                      08/09/2017
 15/02/2017                      08/09/2017
```

Comment: What package do you use to read the excel file into R?

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes @schwantke, it helps me, thanks! The libraries I'm using are: 
library("readxl")
library("openxlsx")
library("lubridate")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R a date variable is stored as a vector of numbers. So R uses some origin date, like `01.01.1900` (dmy) and adds days to the date according to the number. A simple example: The number `1` would be `02.01.1900`, because this is `1` day after the origin `01.01.1900`. See [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-date-values/), for example.

What you can do is to try the origiin mentioned above. That would be:

```
dates <- as.Date(your_vector_with_numbers, origin= "1900-01-01")
```

But I actually would prefer a solution that Grada Gukovic is probably implying and I would try to handle dates correctly in the first place. To help you with that we would need to know how you load the data.